# jquery element selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can select elements using the following syntax, but what other ways are available?  I didn't know what to search for when trying to determine others. Also, are there ways to select elements via wildcard characters?

```
  //Selection by the element's ID
  $('#mybutton').on('click', function (e) {
     alert('mybutton clicked');
  });

  //Select by the element's css class
  $('.mybuttonclass').on('click', function (e) {
     alert('mybutton clicked');
  });

  //Selection of a tag with name of delete found within a table
  $('table').on('click','a[name=delete]', function (e) {
     alert('table link clicked');
  });
```

So, I can use name, ID or class.  Are there other ways?  A google search term or a link would be helpful.

EDIT:

I had found the selectors page in the documentation, but didn't think this page applied. I had trouble making sense of the page, and thought that it was referring to something else.  That's why I was looking for another search term, because everything was bringing up 'Selectors', and I didn't think that's what I was needing.  apparently I was in the right place after all.

Comment: Google search term: [jquery selectors](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+selectors&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a).

Comment: Typing your question title into google: [jquery element selection](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+element+selection)

Comment: On captures events that bubble up through the dom, so you need to use it on a permanent element higher in the stack than your dynamic elements. I know that's not your question, just throwing it out there. The only one of yours that looks like it should work is the last one, assuming the table is always on the page.

Comment: I found the selectors page, but didn't think that was what I was looking for, hence the reason for my question.  I guess I didn't expect the vast array of options available, and was confused by the page I found.  Being new to jQuery, I expected a simpler explanation as I didn't realize the complexity that could be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Selector    Example       Selects
    *           $("*")                All elements
    #id         $("#lastname")  The element with id=lastname
    .class  $(".intro") All elements with class="intro"
    element $("p")  All p elements
   .class.class $(".intro.demo")    All elements with the classes "intro" and "demo"

    :first  $("p:first")    The first p element
    :last   $("p:last") The last p element
    :even   $("tr:even")    All even tr elements
    :odd    $("tr:odd") All odd tr elements

    :eq(index)  $("ul li:eq(3)")    The fourth element in a list (index starts at 0)
    :gt(no) $("ul li:gt(3)")    List elements with an index greater than 3
    :lt(no) $("ul li:lt(3)")    List elements with an index less than 3
  :not(selector)$("input:not(:empty)")  All input elements that are not empty

    :header $(":header")    All header elements h1, h2 ...
    :animated   $(":animated")  All animated elements

 :contains(text)$(":contains('W3Schools')") All elements which contains the text
    :empty  $(":empty") All elements with no child (elements) nodes
    :hidden $("p:hidden")   All hidden p elements
    :visible    $("table:visible")  All visible tables

    s1,s2,s3    $("th,td,.intro")   All elements with matching selectors

[attribute] $("[href]") All elements with a href attribute
[attribute=value]$("[href='default.htm']")  All elements with a href attribute value equal to "default.htm"
[attribute!=value]$("[href!='default.htm']")    All elements with a href attribute value not equal to "default.htm"
[attribute$=value]$("[href$='.jpg']")   All elements with a href attribute value ending with ".jpg"

    :input  $(":input") All input elements
    :text   $(":text")  All input elements with type="text"
    :password   $(":password")  All input elements with type="password"
    :radio  $(":radio") All input elements with type="radio"
    :checkbox   $(":checkbox")  All input elements with type="checkbox"
    :submit $(":submit")    All input elements with type="submit"
    :reset  $(":reset") All input elements with type="reset"
    :button $(":button")    All input elements with type="button"
    :image  $(":image") All input elements with type="image"
    :file   $(":file")  All input elements with type="file"

    :enabled    $(":enabled")   All enabled input elements
    :disabled   $(":disabled")  All disabled input elements
    :selected   $(":selected")  All selected input elements
    :checked    $(":checked")   All checked input elements
```

Comment: This is what I was expecting to find when I did my initial search. Thanks @PranayRana

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of selectors in jQuery! Look here [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

I have found [Alternative jQuery Documentation - For Version 1.7](http://jqapi.com/) a bit easier to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) has the best documentation on JQuery selectors u must check it out.

Comment: To be honest, no.  It's missing a number of selectors and it has very little detail.

Comment: To be honest, w3schools is a [terrible reference](http://w3fools.com/).  Why not link to jquery [itself](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)?

Comment: To be honest ,for someone who has just started with JQuery this much are enough.Otherwise "Too Many Cooks Spoil the Food".

Comment: I agree with you @MehulHingu.  This page is a bit clearer for me, as I'm rather new to jQuery (and javascript as well).  The examples make more sense to me.  I find the jQuery documentation to be a bit cryptic and hard to understand.

Comment: A must read for anyone who uses w3schools [w3schools an intervention](http://w3fools.com/). I used to use it myself, and after finding this i stopped immediately, some very good points are presented here.